# Keeping unit tests in separate files in D

Tags: unit-testing, testing, d

I want to test my code written in D. I am using DUB to build the project (but the config is fairly basic so far: just the name and `dunit` dependency).

I have seen in many projects that unit tests are placed next to the actual code (e.g. http://wiki.dlang.org/Unittest#Placement).

While this is IMO ok for small modules and simple tests, what if I really wanted to test my code?

In Java (and other JVM languages) the convention is quite the opposite - to keep the tests in separate files (usually mirroring the packaging of units under tests).

**Is it possible to have separate files for unit tests in D?**

I'd love to have a classic setup:

```
dub.json
/source/mylib/app.d
/tests/mylib/app_tests.d
```

with the file `app_tests` (as other files unter `tests`) integrated with DUB - compiled/run only during `--unittests` etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know about conventions, but I recently came across such a solution for DUB:

```
{
    "name": "sample",
    "description": "sample app",

    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "application",
            "targetType": "executable",
        },
        {
            "name": "unittest",
            "targetType": "executable",
            "targetPath" : "tests",
            "buildOptions": ["unittests"],
            "excludedSourceFiles": ["source/app.d"],
            "sourcePaths": ["tests/"],
            "importPaths": ["tests/"],
            "dependencies": {
                "dunit": ">=1.0.9"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I found the idea in the [DUB sources](https://github.com/rejectedsoftware/dub/blob/master/test/custom-unittest/dub.json). Now if you run `dub` the app will be built, and if you run `dub test` the unit tests (placed in `tests/`) will be run.

This is not perfect and I still haven't worked everything out, but works for my simple needs.

One of the issues is that the separate unit test modules don't have access to private elements in the sources (they may have access to package and public though).

I am not entirely sure if there aren't some side effects of this configuration that I am not aware of. Maybe someone more experienced will validate this approach.

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing stopping you from having `unittest` blocks in one file test code from another module. You can put anything in a `unittest` block that you could put in a normal function. However, you won't be able to access any of the private members of the module being tested unless the `unittest` blocks are in the module being tested. The normal restrictions of access modifiers apply.

There are some folks in the D community who don't like having their unit tests next to what's being tested and choose to put the tests in separate files, but D's unit testing facilities were designed with the idea that you would put the tests right next to the functions that they're testing. This makes it far more obvious when you forget to unit test a function and makes it easier to modify the code and tests together. It's what D's standard library does, and AFAIK, it's what most D programmers choose to do. IMHO, it's far better for maintenance that way, and if you think that it makes a module too large then either you're probably making your modules too large anyway, or you're being too picky about how large a module is. But obviously, it's subjective, and it's up to you whether you want to put your tests in the same module as what they're testing. You just have to keep in mind that if they're separate, then they can't access any private members of the module being tested.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that Java has no modules (however that will change in Java 9 when project Jigsaw finally gets merged in), nor built-in unittests. The story may be different if it did. There are a few valid reasons we keep unittests as close to the piece of code we want to unittest. Most obvious one is the locality. How many times you had to switch between test-package and the regular package where your Java classes are in order to analyse method you are writing unit-test for? :)

To answer your question - I see no reason why you won't be able to have unittests in a separate module. Just give it a try, that is what I would do if I were you.

Comment: I want to keep tests separated to keep the module files small. Then I can have even 10 files testing a single module (with split test purposes, say for extreme values, edge cases and regular inputs). I also wonder if it will be possible to test `private` parts if tests are in separate files. And of course, I don't know how to tell the not-best documented DUB to do what I described..

Comment: If you really want the test in a different file, just put them in the same dir/package. IIRC all modules in the same package have more privileged access to each other.

Comment: Maybe you want to keep the test data in a separate file (and maybe share it with other modules) and the test code in the module itself?